# Realm Xamarin.Forms can't find existing item

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am working to implement *Realm Platform* with synced realms on a Xamarin.Forms Android and iOS app. Using the code below I can create/connect to the realm instance which should store the data and I can add new objects to the instance. However, no matter what I do I cannot get

`realm.Find<Person>("ID-1");`

to return anything. In a `try() catch()` that line returns: "Object reference not set to instance of an object". Using *Realm Studio* I can see the changes being made, and I see that the object which I'm looking for on the app exists.

Furthermore, if I try to query for elements I always get 0, no matter which parameter I specify.

**Model:**

```
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Number {get; set;}

    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    public IList<SoundSnapModel> SnapList { get;}

    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

**Code snippet:**

```
 var credentials = Credentials.Nickname("Thanos", false);
 var InstanceId = "instance-name";
 var serverURL = new Uri("realms://" + InstanceId + "/~/testRealm3");
 var AUTH_URL = new Uri("https://" + InstanceId + "/auth");
 var user = await User.LoginAsync(credentials, AUTH_URL);

 var configuration = new QueryBasedSyncConfiguration(serverURL, user);
 var realm = Realm.GetInstance(configuration);

 realm.Write(() => realm.Add(new Person { Id = "ID-1", Number = 123,     
 DeviceId = "something", DeviceName = "something" }));  // works without issue
 Debug.WriteLine("Added new person!!");

 var elements = realm.All<Person>().Where(e => e.Number > 100);
 Debug.WriteLine("Found the object list: " + elements.Count() + "  "); // returns 0

 var currentObject = realm.Find<Person>("ID-1"); // triggers the exception mentioned above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QueryBasedSyncConfiguration` was added after I left the Realm Xamarin team but I think it's not working because you're not configuring it fully.

Looking at the [docs](https://docs.realm.io/sync/using-synced-realms/syncing-data#using-query-based-synchronization) it is fairly clear you must **setup the subscription**.

*By default, a query-based synchronized Realm contains no data. Instead, the client application must choose, or subscribe to, which subset of  data in the corresponding Realm on the server it wants to synchronize.*

You don't create a subscription as they describe:

`var subscription = realm.All<Person>().Where(e => e.Number > 100).Subscribe();`

I'm fairly sure that, even though you are creating data locally, it's effectively not existing locally until you have a subscription which would include it.